# Angular change detection error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I am getting this error when input binding value is changed inside the component from null/undefiend to some value. Below is the URL for sample code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h61csi

Why do I get this error? Someone please explain me how to resolve this without setTimeout.

Comment: Can you try moving your code from NgAfterViewInit to NgOnInit

Comment: @djain4 I did tried that too. It is throwing same error.

Comment: Try to put initialization of items inside ngOnInit of appComponent

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/ go thru this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put setting `this.selectedItem` in a `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if(!this.selectedItem) {
    this.selectedItem = this.items[1];
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }
});
```

To know why and when this error occurs you can read about `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` here - https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: Actually I am trying to achieve without using setTimeout. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @vatz response with small correction. We don't need 'this.cdr.markForCheck()', its required only when we have onpush change detection used in the component.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if(!this.selectedItem) {
    this.selectedItem = this.items[1];
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to achieve without using setTimeout. Thanks

Comment: Then you can use this.cdr.detectChanges(). Which will manually trigger Change Detection. (cdr => ChangeDetectionRef)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to resolve your issue is to redesign your components a bit. Your child component shouldn't pass values back to the parent component, especially if the parent component already knows what the values are, i.e the AppComponent in your case, knows exactly what the values of the selectedItem and the items array are, so you can put the logic from the AfterViewInit hook of the child component in the parent component. Simply change the selectedItem field to:

```
private _selectedItem: Object;

public get selectedItem() {
    return this._selectedItem ? this._selectedItem : this.items[1];
}
```

And then remove the code from the AfterViewInit hook in the child component and everything should work without errors. Otherwise, you will have to use setTimeout.

Comment: yeah i can do that way.
But does that mean, in angular there is no option to re-initialize binding value inside the component when it renders? 
I am going to use it as a reusable library so I need to assign default value to selectedItem even if value not passed from parent component.

Comment: Well, one option in such cases would be to initialize the field itself with the default value and then, if something comes through the input binding, it will override the default.
Using the AfterViewInit to update inputs is definitely a bad practice as it causes this error.

Comment: Thanks for answer